GNOME Session Errors
GNOME Session Errors:
I see repeated errors like Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary and warnings about missing or incompatible processes during GNOME startup.
The session sometimes restarts or fails to load correctly.

Please provide a link to a screenshot or photograph of the error message.
